# Linq to sql c# Lamba passing in date

Tags: sql, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to be able to pass in a date of `mm-dd-yyyy`   ( 2-17-2017) as the sql server datetime works for this.

So I was writing a lambda linq to sql query, but I been struggling with the syntax

```
var query = QALists
    //.Where (z => z.Disposition == "Verified")
    //.Where (z => z.CallDate == DateTime.ParseExact("20170215","MMddyyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    //.Where(z => Convert.ToDateTime(20170215, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Where (z => DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}", z.Calldate.ToString() == "2-17-2017")))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(z => new QAList()
                {
                    Agent = z.Agent,
                    ClientName = z.ClientName,
                    Disposition = z.Disposition,
                    CallDate = z.Calldate,
                    Comment = z.Comment,
                    CreatedDateTime = z.CreatedDateTime,
                    CallLength = z.CallLength,
                    IdentityColumnId = z.IdentityColumnId,
                    Number = z.Number,
                    InboundCall = z.InboundCall,
                    OutboundCall = z.OutboundCall,
                    Status = z.Status,
                    QAListId = z.QAListId     
                }).ToList();
```

I commented out my various test   `CallDate` looks like `2017-02-09T07:51:00.76`  in c# from the sql server

How can I use the .Where lambda to simply parse the incoming date?

CallDate looks like this property in poco

```
   public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a constructor to make the date and use the Date property DateTime

```
.Where (z => z.Calldate.Date == new DateTime(2017,2,17).Date)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

Comment: @JeremyMiller -- really you couldn't figure out to swap the 2 and the 17?  In any case I edited it.